# Delete 2D_array error

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, delete-operator

I am trying here to delete 2D array with no result.

i have this struct:

```
struct Node {
 char Object[32];
 int Link_num;
 char **Links;
 Node *Next;
};
```

In one of the functions i am creating 2d array dynamically as shown:

```
record->Links = new char*[record->Link_num];
    for (int i = 0; i < record->Link_num; i++) {
        record->Links[i] = new char[16];
        cin.getline(record->Links[i], 16, '\n');
    }
```

And now when i am trying to delete the array in some delete function:

```
if (ptr->Link_num > 0) {
        for (int i = ptr->Link_num; i > 0; --i)
            delete[] ptr->Links[i];
        //delete[] ptr->Links;
    }
```

I get this error:

```
Exception thrown at 0x50EE436B (ucrtbased.dll) in Test_10.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFDFDFDED. occurred.
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `int i = ptr->Link_num - 1 ` ?

Comment: Why are you messing with `new` `delete` at all instead of simply using a `std::vector<std::string>`?

Comment: Gill Bates, you are right! Problem solved changing this condition. Thanks)
πάντα ῥεῖ, seems to be a solve to a problem, didn't learnt how to use vectors yet. Thank you)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for (int i = ptr->Link_num; i > 0; --i)`, the loop is performed from `ptr->Link_num` to `1` (i.e. `[ptr->Link_num, 0)`). But the range of array is `[0, ptr->Link_num)`, which doesn't contain `ptr->Link_num`. So you're getting out of the range of the array. The behavior is undefined, and you're "lucky" to get an error for it.

Change it to

```
for (int i = ptr->Link_num - 1; i >= 0; --i)
    delete[] ptr->Links[i];
delete[] ptr->Links;
```

or (you don't need to loop it in reverse order)

```
for (int i = 0; i < ptr->Link_num; ++i)
    delete[] ptr->Links[i];
delete[] ptr->Links;
```

Comment: Ops, didn't pay attention to that. Problem solved, thank you ))